# Visual Studio 2015 - Opening two projects in debug mode

Tags: asp.net, iis-express, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I'm using Visual Studio Ultimate 2015 CTP (Version 14.0.22512.0 DP), and create two asp.net 5 vnext web applications.
When one is running, and I'm starting the second one with the context menu "Debug->Start new instance" option, the IIS Express crashes instantly (Internet Explorer opens firstly the second project, and then instantly closes both, Chrome simply display only that the page doesn't exist).
The only trace that I found is in the Event Viewer, a Warning from IIS Express:

> The directory specified for caching compressed content C:\Users\Alek\AppData\Local\Temp\iisexpress\IIS Temporary Compressed Files\Clr4IntegratedAppPool is invalid.  Static compression is being disabled.

Any suggestions how to fix this? It's hard to work on a multi-tier project when only one project can be run at a time.

When I created manually above folder, nothing is logged to the event viewer, but the IIS Express still crashes. On Visual Studio 2013 I can run two instances of two Web Applications withtout any problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not a solution, but a workaround which I found - running two instances of Visual Studio 2015 allow to run two projects.

Comment: How to run multiple instances of project in IIS Express using VS 2015. Unable to do it using applicationhost.config file

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you set your solution to use multiple startup projects and add all the projects you need to debug

Really easy steps to follow here:
http://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/paulnieuwelaar/2015/04/07/debug-multiple-projects-at-the-same-time-in-visual-studio

Still not as easy as previous versions of visual studio